# Ubuntu doesn't complete download and install; install closes without warning

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit from Windows 7.

I followed the steps which described at
[http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows (wayback link)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130729232535/http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows)

Step 5:

> Wait until Ubuntu is downloaded and installed. This can take quite a while — the downloaded file size is around 500MB - but you can keep using your computer throughout.

Step 6:

> When the installation is complete, you’ll be prompted to restart your computer. Click 'Finish' to restart.

I never make it to Step 6 nor do I see the restart prompt after Step 5. The installation just closes itself without any warning.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the ubuntu iso file and install it from usb.
Here's how to create a bootable usb
[usb installation for ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Comment: Ok. I am trying now. I will tell you the results.

Comment: I tried but result is the same it's closing suddenlly.

Comment: When did it close this time?